# Query database to get conditional monthly counts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query to get the monthly visits counts:

```
SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', started_at), 'Month YYYY')) AS month, COUNT(id)::int
FROM   visits
GROUP  BY DATE_TRUNC('month', started_at)
ORDER  BY DATE_TRUNC('month', started_at);
```

which results in:

```
[
  {"month"=>"March     2017", "count"=>8},
  {"month"=>"April     2017", "count"=>21},
  {"month"=>"May       2017", "count"=>5}
]
```

How can I change/improve my query to get the counts split by whether `email` column from another table (`users`) contains certain domain?

So it'll be something like:

```
[
  {"month"=>"March     2017", "with_domain_count"=>4, "withoout_domain_count"=>4},
  {"month"=>"April     2017", "with_domain_count"=>11, "withoout_domain_count"=>10},
  {"month"=>"May       2017", "with_domain_count"=>4, "withoout_domain_count"=>1}
]
```

There's `visits.user_id` foreign key. Domain is `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can join the tables:

```
SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', v.started_at), 'Month YYYY')) AS month,
       COUNT(id)::int,
       SUM( (v.email like '%@gmail.com')::int) as withDomain,
       SUM( (v.email not like '%@gmail.com')::int) as withoutDomain
FROM visits v LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON v.userid = v.userId
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', v.started_at)
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', v.started_at);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation by the use of `case` inside `count` function to check for certain criteria:

```
select RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', v.started_at), 'Month YYYY')) as month,
    COUNT(case 
            when u.email like '%@somedomain.com'
                then id
            end) as with_domain_count,
    COUNT(case 
            when u.email not like '%@somedomain.com'
                then id
            end) as without_domain_count
from visits v
join users u on u.id = v.user_id
group by DATE_TRUNC('month', v.started_at)
order by DATE_TRUNC('month', v.started_at);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure join needs to be performed, since `email` column is in `users` table, not in `visits` table

Comment: @AndreyDeineko - Yes you can join the tables and then find aggregates. Updated the answer.